# Thread holding up socket

Tags: multithreading, sockets, python-2.7

My app receives jobs to do from a web server through sockets. At the moment when a job is running on the app I can then only send 2 more messages to the app before it won't receive any more.

```
def handlemsg (self, data):
    self.sendmsg (cPickle.dumps('received')) # send web server notification received

    data = cPickle.loads(data)

    print data

    # Terminate a Job
    if data[-1] == 'terminate':
        self.terminate(data[0])

    # Check if app is Available
    elif data[-1] == 'prod':
        pass

    # Run Job
    else:
        supply = supply_thread(data, self.app)
        self.supplies[data['job_name']] = supply
        supply.daemon = True
        supply.start()
```

I can send as many prods as I like to the server. But once I send a Job that activates a thread then responses become limited. For some reason it will allow me to send another two prods while the job is running... But after that the print message will not appear it just keeps on working.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was running my data through a datagram socket configuration. I switched to a socketstream and it seemed to resolve it.

http://turing.cs.camosun.bc.ca/COMP173/notes/PySox.html

Was helpful in the resolution.